# Android Emulator - Connecting two emulator Instances via networking with different API-Level

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to develope an android application (with min-API-Level 28) with Java that communicates with an other device over a socket connection. One device is creating a Server instance and the other device should connect to this server.

For this purpose, I'm using Android-Emulator instances provided by Android Studio.

I followed the instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#connecting , but encountered that the provided IP-Adress ranges are not the same for every API-Level.
One Emulator-Instance running API 28 is using 192.168.232.0/24 address range, the other one running API-30 is using the provided 10.0.2.0/24 range.

So given the following scenario:
the Server (running on an API-28 Emulator-Instance) is creating the ServerSocket:

```
this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
// 192.168.232.2 is the device's IP-Address IF(!) the Emulator-Instance uses API Level 28
// 55555 the specific ServerPort
this.serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.232.2", 55555));
```

and after that accept incoming connections:

```
client = this.serverSocket.accept();
```

the Client (running on an API-30 Emulator-Instance) is trying to connect to this Server:

```
this.server = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 55556);
```

as described in the provided docs, 10.0.2.2 is the developement Device aka my Computer and 55556 a chosen local-port.

On the Server-Instance I added a redirect via the android emulator console

```
redir add tcp:55556:55555
```

But the Client can't connect to the Server. So far I'm clueless.
Any ideas what went wrong here?

@Edit - Tried to clarify that I'm using Android Emulators instead of real Devices

Comment: Do not bind the server socked to an ip. Just open the port. Then the client should connect to the server ip so it should be this.client=new Socket(192.168.232.2).

Comment: It is strange that you speak about emulators and devices. Now tell what you use. And you should use two devices on the same wifi network. You cannot use two emulators. Not even one.

Comment: Sorry, this.client=new Socket(192.168.232.2, 55556).

Comment: @blackapps Thanks, for the reply. I am using two Emulator instances provided by Android Studio. The entire problem is based on connecting these two together, like it's described on the provided link, which did not work out for me. I will try to change the ServerSocket Implementation, as you stated and will report back.